# I cannot mount a partition as the home directory

Tags: home-directory

My problem is that I installed ubuntu 14 and I forgot to make a special part for home directory, so how can I mount it???

Comment: Can you login into Ubuntu? and if yes what to you get? What username did you choose? Your home-dir should be /home/<username>

Comment: Best to just follow the step by step instructions. You need an ext4 partition, and copy files from /home into partition, then edit fstab. Details: To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
 But if new install, it may just be easier to reinstall. But you have to use Something Else to choose the partition you want as /home.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not create a home partition, there is nothing to mount.  If you want to create a home partition, you will need to resize your root partition, create the home partition, and edit `/etc/fstab`.

- To resize and create partitions, it would be easiest to use [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php).
- To add the newly created home partition to `/etc/fstab`, add a line that looks like this:

  ```
  UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX /home       ext4    defaults        0       2
  ```

  Check the output of `blkid` to replace XXXXXX with the **uuid** of your home partition.  Change *ext4* to correspond to the filesystem of your partition.

  See the [`fstab` manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/fstab.5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would say he had no home partition. So he needs to resize the full partition of / and then create a new one and mount it as home.
I recommend doing that with GParted or KDE Partition manager (included in Kubuntu Install image).
But to do that you need to boot your system from a live CD, because you cannot change the root partition if it is still mounted. I use the Kubuntu Install Image for that.
To get it up and running first move all data from the original /home folder to the new partition, that must be done in the live system.
If all Users Data is transferred to the new partition, you can reboot.
I do that and now I would have my home partition at /dev/sda2 .

```
mount | grep dev/sda  
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 ...
/dev/sda2 on /home type ext4 ...
```

br
wikrie